# Can't create virtual switch in Hyper-V on Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I'm trying to create a virtual switch on a Windows 8.1 laptop. It has a physical WiFi network and a USB connected Ethernet connection.

When I try to create any sort of virtual network (External/Internal/Private) I get the following error:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this issue was due to the Intel Dual Band Wireless AC7260 drivers. After installing the latest driver version being 17.0.2.5 this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the IP Helper service is not responding. So, you can try restarting the `"IP Helper"` service in Services console and if any related to DLL file was corrupted or blocked by any other application like Anti virus.. you can do clean boot. And also run SFC /scannow command using runas administrator option via command prompt to scan your system if any windows files repair.

Hope this helps,